# LINQ to XML and ViewList

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I seems to run into problem, and not sure how to make it work.
I am trying to take data from XML by using linq and the code works, however when i try use this linq data as DataSource for the ListView, i am getting an error.

How can I make it work ? How do i convert my var variable to proper variable so ListView with the Pager will accept it ?

Any examples of the code will be highly appreciated.

That is the error i am getting:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: ListView with id 'showTopics' must have a data source that either implements ICollection or can perform data source paging if AllowPaging is true.

Source Error:

Line 28:         showTopics.DataSource = archievePosts;
Line 29:         showTopics.DataBind();
```

And the code-behind:

```
String xmlpath = Server.MapPath("App_Data/topics.xml");
var archievePosts = from a in XElement.Load(xmlpath).Elements("topic")
                    where (DateTime.Parse(a.Element("topicdate").Value) <= DateTime.Parse(hDate.Text))
                    select new
                    {
                        topic_id = a.Attribute("id").Value.ToString(),
                        topic_subject = a.Element("topicname").Value,
                        topic_date = a.Element("topicdate").Value
                    };
showTopics.DataSource = archievePosts;
showTopics.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ToArrayList()` or `ToList()`

But are you sure that you are getting the data or there is a problem, try to debug and see the value of the ArchivePosts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i am sure i am getting data. I took Pager off while debugging and it was returning proper values. Going try your method now.